# Translate JQuery code to Javascript probleme with "prepend"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to translate this jquery code :
`$('#zone').prepend('<p><strong>' + login + '</strong> ' + message + '</p>');`

I tried that:
`document.getElementById('zone').innerHTML = '<p><strong>' + login + '</strong> ' + message + '</p>';`

but the problem is i don't know where i can put ".prepend".
thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to stick to `innerHTML`, you can just do this:

```js
const zone = document.getElementById('zone');
zone.innerHTML = '<p><strong>' + login + '</strong> ' + message + '</p>' + zone.innerHTML;
```

Another idea is to use dynamic element and avoid rewriting your `#zone` HTML (that's important when you have things like inputs there, because the first example will clear them out):

```js
const p = document.createElement('p');
const strong = document.createElement('strong');
strong.textContent = login;
p.append(strong, ' ' + message);
document.getElementById('zone').prepend(p);
```

Comment: Thank you Robo , for this solutions and your explanation ,all work !

Answer (score 0):

You should add it to the beginning of the string as follows:

```
var zone = document.getElementById('zone');
const content = zone.innerHTML;
zone.innerHTML = `<p><strong>${login}</strong>${message}</p>` + content;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Node#firstChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/firstChild) property and [`Node#inserBefore`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore) method, so it won't recreate existing child elements.

```
// create the `p` tag and set its HTML content
const p = document.createElemnt('p');
p.innerHTML = '<strong>' + login + '</strong> ' + message ;

const ele = document.getElementById('zone');
// insert the created p tag element before the first element
ele.insertBefore(p, ele.firstChild) ;
```

Comment: There's `prepend()` method for that.

Comment: @RoboRobok : yes, and it's an alternate approach with older browser support. Its first time I heard about the prepend function in JS :) learned a new thing today

Comment: @RoboRobok with prepend you can use html string itself

Comment: Yes, I know. `prepend()` works just like `append()`. Unlike `appendChild()`, it can also take text.